# Is that a series, which converges absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}
$$
I dont know how to show that this is absolutely convergent. 
Taking the absolut value $$\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}\right|$$ leads to
$$
\frac{1}{n^n}
$$ 
which obviously converges. However whether or not is  absolutely convergent is not obvious.

Comment: Since $1/n^n > 0$, convergence is the same as absolute convergence for that series.

Comment: Are you sure that the summations start at $n=0$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $0^0 = 1$, for integer exponents, that is the natural definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a couple of confusions related to absolute convergence; let me attempt to clear them up.

We say that a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is *absolutely convergent* if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert a_n\rvert$ converges.

So, to establish that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}$ converges absolutely, all that you must show is that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\lvert\frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}\right\rvert=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^n}
$$
converges.

We call this absolute convergence because the claim is that the sum of the absolute values converges.  It is a nice property, because it turns out that absolute convergence implies convergence (and we have more tests for series with positive terms than general series); it also leads to some other nice properties, such as the ability to rearrange the terms of a series without changing its value.

(Note that there is also another mistake in your presentation: it is NOT true that
$$
\left\lvert\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\right\rvert=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert a_n\rvert,
$$
unless it is the case that either every non-zero term has the same sign.)

Comment: @ Nicholas,thx..

Answer (score 0):

$$n^n>n!\qquad\to\qquad0<\dfrac1{n^n}<\dfrac1{n!}\qquad\to\qquad0<\sum\dfrac1{n^n}<\sum\dfrac1{n!}=e$$ Also, $\displaystyle\sum\frac1{n^n}$ is strictly increasing, since its general term is strictly positive, i.e., $\dfrac1{n^n}>0$, so there can be no divergence due to oscillation either. Therefore, $\displaystyle\sum\frac1{n^n}$ is convergent due to it being both bound and monotonous, meaning that $\displaystyle\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}$ is absolutely convergent. Also, $\lim_{n\to0^+}n^n=1$.